# How to handle subclasses needing different method signatures for the overriden function?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, inheritance

I have an abstract class that represents chess pieces, it has an abstract method `isMoveValid(Square futurePosition, PieceColor color)` which checks if the piece moving to that square is valid or not, if the move is valid but there is an opponent piece on that square then the piece is trying to capture not just move.

I believed that the function is against the single responsibility principle, since it captures and checks if the move is valid, I wanted to remove the capturing logic and move it to a standalone function in the abstract class called `willCapture()` and make `isMoveValid()` use that function to check if the move is intended to capture.

The main issue is that each piece has its own logic for capturing (i.e a pawn can only capture diagonally), some values needed for the logic are already calculated in `isMoveValid()` and I did not want to repeat the same code twice, so I thought we can pass it to `willCapture()` as a parameter but some pieces do not need those values, how can I make this method accept different parameters depending on what object is calling it?

I thought about the strategy pattern by making a `CaptureStrategy` interface and a class that implements it for each piece and making `willCapture()` take a `CaptureStrategy` but that felt like I added an extra step and I am not really interested in switching the strategy dynamically since each piece will only ever use one strategy, is there a design pattern that solves such a problem?

Code snippets:

Pawn's capture logic in `isMoveValid()`:

```
    int yPosDifference = Math.abs(futurePosition.getY() - this.getPosition().getY());
    int xPosDifference = Math.abs(futurePosition.getX() - this.getPosition().getX());
    if (Board.getBoard().isSquareOccupied(futurePosition) && xPosDifference == 1 && yPosDifference == 1)
    {
        Piece capturedPiece = Board.getBoard().getPieceFromSquare(futurePosition);
        if (capturedPiece.getColor() != this.getColor())
        {
            capture(capturedPiece);
            return true;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cannot capture your own piece.");
    }
    return false;
```

Queen's capture logic in `isMoveValid()`:

```
        if (Board.getBoard().isSquareOccupied(futurePosition)) {
        Piece capturedPiece = Board.getBoard().getPieceFromSquare(futurePosition);
        if (capturedPiece.getColor() != this.getColor())
        {
            capture(capturedPiece);
            return true;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cannot capture your own piece.");
    }
    return false;
```

Pawn's `isMoveValid()` requires `yPosDifference` and `xPosDifference` in other parts of `isMoveValid()` but is also required in the capture logic, if we calculate it inside `willCapture()` we will have duplicate code and if we pass it as a parameter then the Queen and other pieces will not make use of it.

Comment: *"some values needed for the logic are already calculated in isMoveValid()"- " but some pieces do not need those values"*. Could you please tell us precisely which values, or give an example where we can actually see your issue?

Comment: ... and why does `ChessPiece.isMoveValid` require a piece color as parameter? I guess a chess piece should know its color already.

Comment: Edited the question, now has code snippets.
@DocBrown it is there to avoid a player moving a piece that aren't theirs.
`if (this.getColor() != color) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The piece chosen was not your piece.");`
It takes the current player's color (i.e white or black) and checks if the color of the current piece is the same as the player. I probably should rename the parameter.

Comment: I see an issue with your separation in that I believe that in some circumstances isMoveValid() and willCapture() are related and need to exchange information.  In the case of a pawn, a diagonal move is only valid, if it *is* capturing a piece.

Comment: Your example still misses the crucial part you were asking about, the intended signatures of `willCapture` - come on - that is the core of your question, and you are holding this back? I think you can do better,

Comment: ... and what does `capture` do? That name puzzles me, because `isMoveValid` should only test if a move is valid, I guess, not change the state of the board in any way.

Comment: The issue is the arguments of `willCapture()` that's why I didn't add any, in the case of the Queen it would be `willCapture(Square futurePosition)` in the case of a pawn it would be `willCapture(Square futurePosition, int yPosDifference, int xPosDifference)` or `willCapture(Square futurePosition)` and recalculate `yPosDifference` and `xPosDifference` inside the method, which will result in duplicate code since they were already calculated in `isMoveValid()`

`capture` calls `Board.getBoard().removePieceFromBoard(capturedPiece);` but with some print statements for debugging.

Comment: It seems to me you are defeating the purpose of polymorphism by leaving the burden of calling all these methods in the right way up to the client of the piece. Why not just have a Piece.Move(newPosition) method (may be with an extra parameter that tells whether to actually perform the move or not) that returns a report? Like Success or Failure with the reason for failing? That would make all your troubles disappear.

Comment: But where do you intend to call `willCapture`? Why does it have to be an abstract method with a common signature? Why does it really require parameters yPosDifference and xPosDifference? For checking if a pawn will capture a piece, one only need the "future position", as well as for any other piece. There seems to something wrong in your function's logic, but I cannot tell you really what it is since you don't gave us the full picture.

Comment: ... and concerning the "duplicate code": if you have duplicate code in two methods, refactor it out into a separate method which can be called from the two former ones. Don't be afraid of the same calculation happening twice, that's a negligible performance impact.

Comment: ... and besides that - consider to redesign `isMoveValid` not to execute any capturing on the board - a method which tests something should not secretly change the board's state.

Comment: @DocBrown I agree, `isMoveValid` shouldn't capture, I am just trying to connect the dots is all, `isMoveValid` should take in account that a capture might occur, since moving diagonally on a capture for a pawn is a valid move but isn't in any other scenario, I most likely would use it in the `move` method and let it capture, as in move to a certain Square, but if the square has an opponent piece then it means to capture. `yPosDifference` and `xPosDifference` are required to ensure that the position of the enemy piece is diagonal to the piece doing the moving/capturing.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that different signatures would be needed suggest that something is wrong in the polymorphic design. It's not very useful to have a `Piece` abstraction,  but have to use each `Piece` differently. This is a design that is not [OCP compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), since for every new kind of Piece, you'd have to modify the code that use the Pieces.

Typically, we can expect that a chess piece knows its position and its color.  But a piece does generally not know the position of the other pieces that might be on the way and make the move impossible. Fortunately, wa can expect that the board, knows the pieces that are on each square.

With this in mind, to check the move, you'd use `isMoveValid(Square futurePosition,  Board board)`.  There is all the information needed for every to find out if the move is valid, using a different implementation of the same `isMoveValid()`. They would just verify differently if the `futurePosition` is in range,  and -- if needed -- the pieces that are on the way and/or on the target position).

Comment: `isMoveValid()` is already doing that, the board is a singleton so I get the instance inside of the method when needed instead of passing it as an argument, the issue is the process of capturing, I can make it return true if the move intended is to capture and is valid, but then how would board know how to update it? I'm thinking maybe an observer pattern where I can notify the board that a capture is in process.

Comment: @MohammadSrahin if the board is singleton, how will your game be able to simulate future moves anticipating on possible moves of the adversary (e.g minimax or allha-beta pruning) ? the Singleton pattern is to be used in exceptional situations only, keeping in mind that it creates hidden couplings and constraints.

Comment: @MohammadSrahin but your question remains valid; the responsibilities of the board, the pieces and the game need to be clearly defined. If the piece makes the capture, it has to inform the board of the removal of the piece. if the board takes note of moves that are known to be valid, the board could manage the capture based on the target position. But may be the game  observes the board and makes the capture based on the move. All 3 approaches have pros and cons.

Comment: The Board class has a `List<Piece>` that keeps track of all the pieces that are currently on the board and their positions, I made it a singleton so that the state is ensured to be the same across all classes, is this an incorrect usage of the singleton pattern? Also the program is meant for two human players, so there is no need to simulate future moves, imo.

Comment: @MohammadSrahin if there is only an actual situation for two humans, your singleton will work. No worry. But the pieces are coupled to it for their movements. So you won’t be able to reuse them in another context. So if one day you need several boards (e.g. simulation, or just to be able to manage simultaneous game, like a grandmaster against several remote openents) you’d need to rewrite it completely. OO design aims to reduce coupling and promote reuse.  So, yes the singleton pattern is misused in this situation.

Comment: The intent of the singleton is “Ensure a class only has one instance, and provide a global point of access to it”. While you use the second part as a convenience, the question is: is it really necessary to ensure that there is only one instance of the board? In my opinion, everytime a singleton is used without this necessity of uniqueness is a symptom of possible misuse/antipattern.

Comment: A chess program could easily let you play three games at the same time, plus analyse half a dozen more games, and would need nine chessboards for that. One case where you should not use singletons: If you need more than one instance.

Answer (score 1):

Single responsibility:

IsMoveValid: Look at the name. The function will return YES or NO depending on whether the move is valid or not. It will not perform the move.

PerformMove: Look at the name. It has one responsibility: To perform the move with all its side effects. Should never be called if the move is invalid (might throw an exception, or better assert because calling it for an invalid move is a programming error that needs to be fixed).

PerformMoveIfValid: Look at the name. It has clearly two responsibilities. Return NO if the move is not valid, or perform the move with all its side effects then return YES if the move was valid. Whether you are worried about the two responsibilities is up to you, I'm happy if the name expresses clearly what the function does.

Comment: Technically I can make it check if the move is valid in the client and make `move()` have only a single responsibility, but this defeats abstraction doesn't it? If we want to make one entry point to the system then we will have a method that will do more than one thing, is there a way to make it truly single responsibility?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to think clearly about which methods need to be *part of the public interface of all chess pieces*, and which are *internal implementation details of a particular piece*.

If `willCapture` is only ever used inside the class, it can be private. Then it doesn't need to be part of the interface / abstract class, and doesn't need to have the same parameters - or even exist at all - in particular sub-classes.

On the other hand, if you want to use `willCapture` from *outside* the class, on any type of piece, then it needs to be public, and you need a standard set of parameters for it *otherwise you won't be able to call it*. That doesn't mean you can't share any internal logic, but rather than `isMoveValid` calling `willCapture`, you would make *both* methods call some other helper.

The pawn, for example, has a number of "special abilities", which might have their own helpers: `isValidStartingRowMove`, `isValidForwardMove`, `isValidStandardCapture`, `isValidEnPassantCapture`. Since these are internal, they can have whatever input and output makes them useful to the rest of the class.